# The clang linker errors when using std::visit for variant only with rtti and exceptions

Tags: c++, c++17

When using std visit, the linker complains with rtti and exceptions.

**Sample**

```
  int main(){
  std::variant<int, float> rf;
  rf = 1;
  std::visit([](auto&& arg){
      using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
      if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
             std::cout << "OK";
    }, rf);

  }
```

If I compile above *without* rtti and exceptions, it works:

```
$ /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions
```

But it does not compile otherwise.

```
$ /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp
```

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>         "typeinfo for std::bad_variant_access", referenced from:
>             _main in test-e84443.o
>         "vtable for std::bad_variant_access", referenced from:
>             std::bad_variant_access::bad_variant_access() in test-e84443.o
>         NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
>       ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>       clang-6.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: As I know the variant/visit has several issues with clang: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33222